# Verified Application presented as "Unverified" to End Users

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-developers-console, google-cloud-console

My company has an application that was verified through the Google OAuth Review/Verification process and is listed as "Published" in the Cloud Console; however, end users are starting to receive the "This app isn't verified" warning when needing to re-authorize.

We tried emailing them Google Cloud Platform/API Trust & Safety Team directly but immediately received the reply "Please note that your email was not received because api-dev-oauth-verification@google.com is not a monitored alias."

Since the application is verified in the console, the "Submit for verification" button is greyed out so we can't contact them that way and we don't want to modify the scopes to require verification again as we want to preserve everything so Google can investigate it in its current state.

That's why I'm reaching out here:

1. Has anyone experienced this before and have any ideas what could be the cause?
2. Anyone know a way to reach the Google Cloud Platform/API Trust & Safety Team without the use of "Submit for verification" button?

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the "api-dev-oauth-verification@google.com is not a monitored alias." message because the address you are trying to send the email to, is a bit wrong.

The correct address to contact the trust and safety team is:

**

> api-oauth-dev-verification@google.com

**

Remember that only the project owner should contact the T&S team.

Comment: So I sent a message to the email you provided and I got an immediate Message Not Received reply like before.

Even more upsetting is that, even though I sent it to ""api-oauth-dev-verification@google.com", the reply said:

"Please note that your email was not received because api-dev-oauth-verification@google.com is not a monitored alias."

Which matches the address I emailed the first time and not this time.

Comment: Yes, I have read some similar testimonies. One thing that you can do is write feedback to the Trust and Safety team: oauth-feedback@google.com.

Another thing you could do is create a Support Case on Google Cloud Platform Support console[1]. The support team could help you verifying the state of your app and contact Trust and Safety team. 

[1] https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346?hl=en

Comment: Thanks! Using that feedback email address eventually got me to the Verification Team so they could investigate the issue.